# Android performance and memory help

Tags: android, performance, memory-management

While looking up peer to peer networking with blue tooth, i wanted to change some of the sprites that were made around.  what i wanted to change was making dummy menus.  As of now there is a start menu and thats it.  So i made a selection menu, and 2 dummy menus that would display the help and mutliplayer option later.

I noticed that i was getting some very strange results with these dummy png files.  It would only display the dummy file and then crash.  After changing around the set up i ran into the error that said the android was low on memory and it crashed.  It pointed me to where I was creating a new object.  I changed the code and then it ran again.  The new problem is that this low memory problem still occurs. I am still new to android development.

Are the .png files I am loading to large and thus it is running low on memory? The 2 new dummy pngs were 400 pixels by 300 pixels.  If this is true, was my design so close to the memory limit that anything new would ruin it?

If i am incorrect, what are some tips you have to help fix the memory problems?

Thanks

Comment: this is very difficult to answer, without knowing what the code is, and how big (in kb) the pics are. Also what version android are you working with? But I don't think its the pictures from what I've seen.

Comment: I am using android version 2.2.  I examined the images and all of them are about 20.0 kb in size.  There are 7 of them.  I understand from many friends who use java that you are not supposed to call the Garbage collector, but is there a way from preventing the mass creation of objects.  IS it better to dynamically crate objects in different functions.  For example all the drawing objects are creating in the draw function and not in the thread.  Or would this not help ether?  What do you do to prevent to much use of memory?

Comment: your problem is not the images - they are not big. You need to rephrase your question (see other questions as examples) and include some of the code. You have given little info for people here to help, but with a better question, you'll get some good ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How big the images are on disk is irrelevant.  It's how big they get when you load them into memory.  If you are using ARGB_8888, 300x400 will turn into a 500K bitmap.  Yes, you need to be much more careful.  See, for instance, here: http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/scarce-commodities-google-android-memory-and-bitmaps/ and
http://www.rbgrn.net/content/363-releasing-bitmap-memory-when-not-needed

Edit: P.S. Welcome to the world of Android.  You have just experienced a painful rite of passage that I call "Bitmap Shock."  One day you will look back on this and laugh. :-)